# Slider transistion with alpinejs

Tags: css, css-transitions, tailwind-css, alpine.js

I'm making a slider with alpineJS and TailwindCSS and having problem with transitions. Please take a look at the following code and point out what I'm doing wrong.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/2.0.2/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/alpinejs/2.8.0/alpine.js"></script>

<div class="relative" x-data="{
            active: 1,
            loop() {
                setInterval(() => { this.active = this.active === 4 ? 1 : this.active+1 }, 3000)
            },
        }" x-init="loop">
  <div class="flex">
    <div class="bg-black">
      <img class="w-full h-96 object-cover opacity-30" alt="1" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1454165804606-c3d57bc86b40?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80" x-show="active == 1" x-transition:enter="transition duration-1000"
        x-transition:enter-start="transform translate-x-full" x-transition:enter-end="transform translate-x-0" x-transition:leave="transition duration-1000" x-transition:leave-start="transform" x-transition:leave-end="transform -translate-x-full">
    </div>
    <div class="bg-black">
      <img class="w-full h-96 object-cover opacity-30" alt="2" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1497366216548-37526070297c?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80" x-show="active == 2" x-transition:enter="transition duration-1000"
        x-transition:enter-start="transform translate-x-full" x-transition:enter-end="transform translate-x-0" x-transition:leave="transition duration-1000" x-transition:leave-start="transform" x-transition:leave-end="transform -translate-x-full">
    </div>
    <div class="bg-black">
      <img class="w-full h-96 object-cover opacity-30" alt="3" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1564069114553-7215e1ff1890?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1489&q=80" x-show="active == 3" x-transition:enter="transition duration-1000"
        x-transition:enter-start="transform translate-x-full" x-transition:enter-end="transform translate-x-0" x-transition:leave="transition duration-1000" x-transition:leave-start="transform" x-transition:leave-end="transform -translate-x-full">
    </div>
    <div class="bg-black">
      <img class="w-full h-96 object-cover opacity-30" alt="4" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1504384308090-c894fdcc538d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80" x-show="active == 4" x-transition:enter="transition duration-1000"
        x-transition:enter-start="transform translate-x-full" x-transition:enter-end="transform translate-x-0" x-transition:leave="transition duration-1000" x-transition:leave-start="transform" x-transition:leave-end="transform -translate-x-full">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**P.S: Please don't refer another slider library or ask me to copy someone else's code. I wanna make this code work**

Thank you.

Comment: Do you like jquery slideshow

Comment: @QuestionsBoy Most of the slideshows are good and will do exactly what I want but I don't wanna use some library or copy someone else's code. This is for learning purpose only.

Comment: @Jerry555555 active value will change every second and would correspond to  x-show with that active value,won't that make your div appear abruptly

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two problems here:

- During the transition the images' position is not correct
- Black background between images

Solution:

- The position is not correct because images need to overlap and they can't overlap with their position set to static (default). So the position need to be absolute so they could overlap and also add overflow hidden so nothing outside the box will be shown. But you need to specify the parent div width and height because of the children being absolute.
- In order not to have the black background move alpine stuff from the image element to its parent div so the whole div will be transitioned not only the image

Here is the complete snippet with the changes:

```html
<link
          href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/2.0.2/tailwind.min.css"
          rel="stylesheet"
        />
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/alpinejs/2.8.0/alpine.js"></script>

        <div
          class="relative"
          x-data="{
                        active: 1,
                        loop() {
                            setInterval(() => { this.active = this.active === 4 ? 1 : this.active+1 }, 3000)
                        },
                    }"
          x-init="loop"
        >
          <div
            style="width: 1350px; height: 901px"
            class="flex overflow-x-hidden relative"
          >
            <div
              class="bg-black absolute"
              x-show="active == 1"
              x-transition:enter="transition duration-1000"
              x-transition:enter-start="transform translate-x-full"
              x-transition:enter-end="transform translate-x-0"
              x-transition:leave="transition duration-1000"
              x-transition:leave-start="transform"
              x-transition:leave-end="transform -translate-x-full"
            >
              <img
                class="w-full h-96 object-cover opacity-30"
                alt="1"
                src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1454165804606-c3d57bc86b40?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80"
              />
            </div>
            <div
              class="bg-black absolute"
              x-show="active == 2"
              x-transition:enter="transition duration-1000"
              x-transition:enter-start="transform translate-x-full"
              x-transition:enter-end="transform translate-x-0"
              x-transition:leave="transition duration-1000"
              x-transition:leave-start="transform"
              x-transition:leave-end="transform -translate-x-full"
            >
              <img
                class="w-full h-96 object-cover opacity-30"
                alt="2"
                src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1497366216548-37526070297c?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80"
              />
            </div>
            <div
              class="bg-black absolute"
              x-show="active == 3"
              x-transition:enter="transition duration-1000"
              x-transition:enter-start="transform translate-x-full"
              x-transition:enter-end="transform translate-x-0"
              x-transition:leave="transition duration-1000"
              x-transition:leave-start="transform"
              x-transition:leave-end="transform -translate-x-full"
            >
              <img
                class="w-full h-96 object-cover opacity-30"
                alt="3"
                src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1564069114553-7215e1ff1890?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1489&q=80"
              />
            </div>
            <div
              class="bg-black absolute"
              x-show="active == 4"
              x-transition:enter="transition duration-1000"
              x-transition:enter-start="transform translate-x-full"
              x-transition:enter-end="transform translate-x-0"
              x-transition:leave="transition duration-1000"
              x-transition:leave-start="transform"
              x-transition:leave-end="transform -translate-x-full"
            >
              <img
                class="w-full h-96 object-cover opacity-30"
                alt="4"
                src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1504384308090-c894fdcc538d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80"
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: I figured about the apline js stuff moving to parent but having problems with positioning. It worked like a charm. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome
As a side note instead of doing ternary operator here
`setInterval(() => { this.active = this.active === 4 ? 1 : this.active+1 }, 3000)`
you can use reminder like this
`setInterval(() => { this.active = (this.active + 1) % 4 }, 3000)` and start the x-show active state from zero index
this is easier and better way of doing rotating range of numbers

Comment: Thanks for the advice but I think my current implementation is more readable to me. If you could tell me how your approach is better I might consider changing.

Comment: What's the point in readable code if it doesn't work?

Answer (score 2):

️ another way :

> ```
> <div class=" relative " x-data="{ activeSlide: 0, slides: {{ \App\Models\Banner::all()->pluck('image')->take(5) }} }">
> <template x-for="(slide,index) in slides" :key="index">
>         <div x-show="activeSlide === index && setTimeout(() => {
>             activeSlide = activeSlide == slides.length-1 ? 0 : activeSlide + 1}, 5000)"
>             class="  px-1 text-white rounded">
>             <img class="h-96 w-full rounded shadow z-0" x-bind:src="`storage/banners/${slide}`">
>         </div>
>  </template>
> </div>
> ```

Comment: Hi, try do add some more description or explaination to your solution (for example, in what it is different from the others)

Comment: Lovely solution you have written here!